# how to call view controller in viewdidload method using segue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have trouble with calling one view controller to another view controller using segue function here is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];
      if (first == NULL) {
           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"first" sender:self];
            NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
       }
}
```

now i got output in console `viewDidLoad`but i can't able to call that Segue.

so i tested in IBaction method there its working fine
here is my IBaction method code.

```
-(IBAction)test{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"first" sender:self];
}
```

kindly some one guide me how to call view controller in viewdidload method.

`note:`this is parent view controller viewdidload method i want to check this condition after splash screen.

Comment: What is `first` variable? Is that condition checking returns success(YES)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think -(void)viewDidLoad is too soon in the life cycle to perform a segue.
Try:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
      [super viewDidAppear:animated];
      if (first == NULL) {
           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"first" sender:self];
            NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
       }
}
```